# Keeping production and development version of an iOS app installed on an iPhone simultaneously

Tags: ios, iphone, testing

I'm developing a universal iOS app. I generally test it both on Simulator and devices. I would also like to have the ability to use the production version of the app, so that I can use the released version as a "normal" user.

But when I build and run the app from Xcode, the App Store installed copy of the app is replaced with the development version of the app.

Is it possible to have both the development and the production (App Store hosted) version of the app simultaneously available on an iOS device?

Comment: The only way you could do this is to change the app's bundle id for your actively-developed app, then change it back when you want to submit.

Comment: ok, thanks for the reply!

Comment: This annoyingly means if you are testing e.g. Game Center as part of your build you have to use the 'correct' bundle-id and then lose your 'production' clean app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apps are distinguished from each other with Bundle Identifier. Two different apps having the same bundle identifier would be treated as the same by the iOS subsystem (for example like in your case, where you have a production and a development version of the same app).

Thus, when you are installing the development version via Xcode, it replaces the App Store (or Test Flight) version.

You can work around this by changing to a different bundle identifier in your Xcode project. Change the field as shown below:

[image]

**P.S.**: Don't forget to revert back to the correct value of the bundle identifier in Xcode after you are done testing the development version.

Comment: Is there a way around this if you need to test e.g. Game Center, which requires the production bundle id?